# Difference between "be a bit of" and" be a bit"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I've heard two sentences:

> - I'm a bit shy person
> - I'm a bit **of** a shy person

If they are both correct **grammatically**, then what's the **point** to add **OF** in the second sentence?

Comment: The first is not grammatically correct. You can say, "I am a bit shy" or "I am a slightly shy person" (or "I am a bit of a shy person"). https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bit_2

Comment: @JamesRandom  It is said "a bit of a something used for saying that someone or something has a particular character, effect, or quality". So basically, If I say that "I'm a bit of a shy person", it doesn't indicate a smaller degree of shyness, and it only shows my particular quality/character. But If I say "I'm a bit shy", then it means that I'm actually a little BIT shy but I'm not entirely shy person. Do I understand it right?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see any difference between being "a bit shy" and "a bit of a shy person". They mean the same thing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is not grammatically correct. It could read:

> I'm a bit shy.

or

> I'm a shy person.

If the intention is to indicate a smaller degree of shyness then the first one is preferred. The second one indicates you are a person with the adjective of 'shy'.
This shows you as an entirely shy person.

In order to indicate this is a partial attribute then 'a bit' is used along with the function word 'of'.

> I'm **a bit of** a shy person.

[[See definition 4 in the Merriam Webster dictionary]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of)

Comment: So, generally, it works this way:
"be a bit + adjective"(I'm a bit smart, It's a bit important)
and "be a bit of +adjectrive +noun" (I'm a bit of a smart guy, It's a bit important subject),
But I can never say:
"be a bit +adjective +noun".
Am I correct?